# Errors occured when extending LockPatternActivity

Tags: android

Inside my application, I wanna extends LockPatternActivity library class :

https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/

```
import com.haibison.android.lockpattern.LockPatternActivity;
import com.haibison.android.lockpattern.R;
import com.haibison.android.lockpattern.*;
public class ExtendPatternActivity extends LockPatternActivity{

}
```

The class which use lockpattern :

```
   public class PatternSetter extends Activity{


Context context = this;
final int REQ_CREATE_PATTERN = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.pattern_setter);

     Settings.Security.setAutoSavePattern(this, true);

 Intent intent = new Intent(LockPatternActivity.ACTION_CREATE_PATTERN, null, this, ExtendPatternActivity.class);
     this.startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CREATE_PATTERN);



}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CREATE_PATTERN: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            char[] pattern = data.getCharArrayExtra(
                    LockPatternActivity.EXTRA_PATTERN);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainTheftActivity.class);
                    context.startActivity(intent);


}
```

But this errors error :

```
04-18 20:37:32.597: E/AndroidRuntime(14712): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start  
activity ComponentInfo{com.tndev.theftahead/com.tndev.theftahead.ExtendPatternActivity}:  
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class 
com.haibison.android.lockpattern.widget.LockPatternView_v14
....
04-18 20:37:32.597: E/AndroidRuntime(14712): Caused by:  
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
04-18 20:37:32.597: E/AndroidRuntime(14712):    at  
android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1163)
04-18 20:37:32.597: E/AndroidRuntime(14712):    at   
android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:845)
04-18 20:37:32.597: E/AndroidRuntime(14712):    at  
com.haibison.android.lockpattern.widget.LockPatternView.<init>(LockPatternView.java:405)
04-18 20:37:32.597: E/AndroidRuntime(14712):    at   
com.haibison.android.lockpattern.widget.LockPatternView_v14.<init>(LockPatternView_v14.java:42)
```

It seems that ExtendPatternActivity cant load the resources in lockpattern library properly?
How should I load resources in the library to my application?
Thanks a lot..

Comment: Already edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for these errors is that I forgot the add some attributes to my activity in the android manifest. 
It should be :

```
    <activity android:name="ExtendPatternActivity"
           android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
           android:screenOrientation="user"
            android:theme="@style/Alp.42447968.Theme.Dark" 
            >   

   </activity>
```

rather than :

```
    <activity android:name="ExtendPatternActivity">   

   </activity>
```

Comment: thanks! You saved my time, I faced the same issue, and your solution is very much correct.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you want to use the resource files, you should use the library as an Android library project. Right click on the project in eclipse, under "Android" property, set the "Is library" to true.

[image]

Then, in your application project, add the library project to the reference.

[image]

Comment: I added the library for sure, but the same errors :(

Comment: How is your ExtendPatternActivity like ?

Comment: public class ExtendPatternActivity extends LockPatternActivity{

}

Answer (score 0):

Just to inform guys who manipulate their android manifest using Application tab that u be careful.By mistake I specified  android:theme="@style/Alp.42447968.BaseTheme.Dark" and I was getting the same big error.So copy the lines:

```
<activity android:name="ExtendPatternActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
android:screenOrientation="user"
android:theme="@style/Alp.42447968.Theme.Dark" 
>   
</activity>
```

as it is.Hope it helps!